# Disabling long press on empty area of home screen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen, htc

I have a HTC Desire X running Android 4.0.4 (not rooted).

If I long press in an empty area on my home screen, it automatically opens the widget which allows me to add/remove apps/widgets on the home screen. This is very inconvenient because I accidentally long press on the home screen few times a day & then without realizing the add/remove widget is on, I accidentally click on an icon or two which adds something I don't want to my home screen. Is it possible to either disable the long press on the home screen action or at least make it less sensitive?

I am not sure if this is a general Android thing or HTC Specific behaviour.

Comment: That is depending on the Launcher used. Are you using HTC's own ROM?

Comment: @t0mm13b - I haven't changed anything since I got the phone - so I assume I am using whatever ROM the phone came with.

Comment: More than likely related to the launcher used on HTC. Try an alternative launcher, there's a few on the Play Store.

Comment: @t0mm13b - I googled a bit but it's not yet clear to me what exactly is a 'Launcher'? Does it have settings I can change?

Comment: The launcher is your home screen - that is where you see the widgets and shortcuts, it also manages the app drawer, where you can see different apps installed. It might help to get a screenshot of it for those more familiar and in the know with HTC devices...

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38298/11251) lists some launchers which have the “Lock Desktop” option. Launchers preinstalled in stock ROMs in most cases do not provide it.