# Is it possible to lock the homescreen from apps moving

Tags: home-screen, recents-screen

Is it possible to lock apps into place on the home screen? My finger keeps moving them from all over the place.

Comment: That depends on the launcher/homescreen you are using. Some offer a "lock desktop" option, which would exactly do that: lock everything in place, so you can launch things, but not move elements placed on the homescreen. What launcher are you using? And would an alternative launcher be an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: I'm using the default launcher that came with the phone. It's the newest version kit kat. I really want to stick with the default launcher. I was just wondering if it was possible with the standard version of android

Comment: In the default launcher there is no such function. And where is your second question by the way.?

Comment: @Akshat in a second post, as it's done at StackExchange sites (one question per post) ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I prevent home screen shortcuts from getting deleted or moved around?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38297/can-i-prevent-home-screen-shortcuts-from-getting-deleted-or-moved-around)